# Ruby on Rails delayed_job gem: method isn't executed at run_at time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I want to use delayed_job to send a notification to user after a specific amount of time has passed. I'm running rails version 4.0.13 on ubuntu.

I followed the README here: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job

Added the following gems:

```
gem 'daemons'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
```

created table delayed_job:

```
rails generate delayed_job:active_record
rake db:migrate
```

generated delayed_job:

```
rails generate delayed_job
```

this created delayed_job.rb in bin dir not script dir. I think this is because i'm using ruby Rails 4.0.13(From the README: Rails 4: replace script/delayed_job with bin/delayed_job).

Contents of my delayed_job.rb:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'config', 'environment'))
require 'delayed/command'
Delayed::Command.new(ARGV).daemonize

RAILS_ENV=development bin/delayed_job start
RAILS_ENV=development bin/delayed_job stop
```

The method that is supposed to run at a specific time:

```
def send_notification
        print "==========SEND_NOTIFICATION============="
        #Some code to send notification to user
end
handle_asynchronously :send_notification, :run_at => Proc.new { 1.minute.from_now }
```

This does create an entry in the db table delayed job with the correct time in the run_at column. However the job is never executed. The attempts column stays 0 and nothing is printed in the terminal.

rake jobs:work does execute the job and removes it from the db.

Comment: Did you start the worker? `rake jobs:work`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. running the rake jobs:work command from the terminal executes the jobs fine, but I want it to execute it automatically.

Comment: You need a worker to run jobs. That command starts one.

Comment: So I only have to enter the command once and after that the jobs are executed at the correct time?

Comment: Provided that worker is running, yes.

Comment: Ok I tested it and you are right, but how do I start it automatically after it's deployed to production? Do I have to run a rake task with Capistrano after deployement?

Comment: https://github.com/platanus/capistrano3-delayed-job You can use this gem